# Instantiate object of a given class implementing an interface and add it to a List<InterfaceX> using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have an Interface "Instruction" and some instructions implement it (Add, Sub, Mul, Jmp...), to execute this instructions I store them on a List object and call an execute() method afterwards. I am reading this instructions from a file and I want to instantiate the proper class by means of the String read from the file but when I invoke the constructor.newInstance(...) I lose the type of the reference and I wont be able to invoke the methods without instanceofs and dirty casts (I want to avoid them).

```java
List<Instruction> res = new ArrayList<>()
String className = "Add";
Class<?> classLoaded = Class.forName("instructions." + className);
Constructor<?> constructor = classLoaded.getConstructors()[0];
Object obj = constructor.newInstance(paramsOfConstructor);
res.add(obj);
```

This works as I want it to work but I want to avoid dirty casts as much as possible

```java
Instruction obj = (Instruction) constructor.newInstance(paramsOfConstructor);
res.add(obj);
```

PD: `paramsOfConstructor` are all the objects/primitives I give to the constructor, I don´t include the code to obtain them because that would be a copy/paste of 30 or so lines. If needed I can copy them also.

Comment: What is `constructor`? Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Is `Class.asSubclass(Instruction.class)` an option?

Comment: @Progman I tried  ```constructor.newInstance(paramsOfConstructor).getClass().asSubclass(Instruction.class)``` but the reference is Class<? extends Instruction> that cannot be done because either I cannot add the object to my List nor I can invoke the execute() method even though I change my List to ```List<Class ? extends Instruction>>```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Class.asSubclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)) method to change your `Class<?>` object returned by `Class.forName(...)` to something you can work with. In combination with the [`getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) method (the singular one, the one without the `s`) you can create a `Constructor` object with a desired type you want. The code will look similar to this:

```
Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread");
Class<? extends Runnable> castedClass = loadedClass.asSubclass(Runnable.class);
Class<?>[] constructorArgumentClasses = new Class<?>[] { String.class }; // pick the constructor: new Thread(String)
Constructor<? extends Runnable> c = castedClass.getConstructor(constructorArgumentClasses);
Runnable t = c.newInstance("abc"); // no casting involved here

System.out.println(t);            // Thread[abc,5,main]
System.out.println(t.getClass()); // class java.lang.Thread
```

You have to rewrite your code that you use `getConstructor()` instead of `getConstructors()` (you are using only one anyway) because this method is returning a `Constructor<? extends T>` object.

Comment: I want to use the getConstructors() method because I dont want to change the code if I change my Constructor signature. Is there any way to do this using the getConstructors() method?

Comment: @Angelixus You don't need to change your code when you change the constructor signature. Using `getConstructor(String.class);` was just an example, you can still use `getConstructor(...);` with an array of `Class<?>` objects to get the constructor you are looking for. You get the array from your `paramsOfConstructor` array. I have edited the answer to show the possible usage.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Sorry to bother you again but I said that I wanted to avoid casting but the ```asSubclass()``` method is doing a cast or am i wrong?

Comment: @Angelixus Check the javadoc on `Class.asSubclass()` what that is doing. Basically it changes a `Class<?>` object which is not helpful to a `Class<? extends T>` object, you have a chance to work with, as seen in the answer. The `c.newInstance(..)` call will recognize the return values as a compatible type `T` instead of a general type `Object`.

Comment: I have just checked the javadoc and everything is Ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Angelixus you can't really completely skip casting when working with reflections, asSubclass is ofc just a cast too, thats the idea of dynamic code like that, there is always some cast, more or less hidden.